# How to install Ubuntu updates after installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, updates

How can I update Ubuntu after installing it since fetching updates during the installation process is taking a long time to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During installation, uncheck these two check boxes.

[image]

Then after installation, restart your machine and run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

---

**Related Links:**

1. [Ubuntu installation guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)
2. [Top things to do after installing Ubuntu Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=top+things+to+do+after+installing+Ubuntu)

Comment: how much size does the updates have ??